# Enabling Google Signals (allow_google_signals) doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have enabled Google Signals in GA4, as well as added the param to Google Tag Manager and set it to true.

I have implemented the correct tag, from Tag Manager, which uses a measurement ID from GA4. The params are visible in the Google Tag Manager javascript:

https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-TLR5HH8

However this seems to be overruled by the Google Analytics javascript, which has the param set to false:

```
[8,"name","allow_google_signals","value",false]
```

I have tried but I can't get Google Signals to work. I hope someone has had the same experience and know the solution.